# How to detect menu item overflow?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to programmatically detect when a menu is overflowed?

My intention is to have a menu item always be visible (`SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS`), except for in the case where it would cause other items to overflow, in which case, don't show the menu item at all. That is:

```
if (overflowed) actionBarMenu.removeItem(id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying where this menu is appearing, so I'll just give an example of what you can do with a Toolbar. What you need to do is to get the reference to the `ActionMenuView` from the `Toolbar` and then call `isOverflowMenuShowing` on it, something like this:

```
private boolean isOverflowShowing(Toolbar toolbar) {
    if(toolbar == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < toolbarView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = toolbarView.getChildAt(i); 
        if(v instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            return ((ActionMenuView)v).isOverflowMenuShowing();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is crude and dirty - and I haven't tested it - but it should get you started.